# Firefox will not even try to install Gnome extensions

Tags: firefox, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I have the `chrome-gnome-shell` package installed. I have the Firefox add-on installed (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/) and I granted it permissions.

When I go here for example: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/, and select the Gnome version and extension version, it only offers to download a Zip file. It does not offer to install and there is no option in the Firefox download dialog for that.

What do I need to do to make this work? I would prefer not to do the fancy work of unzipping, writing down UUIDs and all that just to install an extension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please make sure you have both `gnome-shell-extensions` and `chrome-gnome-shell` packages installed:

Install them as follows:

1. Install gnome-shell-extensions

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions
   ```
2. Install chrome-gnome-shell

   ```
   sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
   ```

After that:

- Install the Gnome tweaks tool as follows:

  ```
  sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
  ```
- Open the GNOME tweaks tool as follows:

  ```
  gnome-tweaks
  ```
- Select extensions from the left side menu and enable them.

Firefox gnome extensions should now install easily from this official web page (simply by flipping the **OFF** button on the top right to **ON**):

https://extensions.gnome.org/

You might need to log out and re-log in for the gnome extensions to work.

Comment: As noted in my question, I have already done all these steps. It still doesn't work and instead it just offers to have me download a zip file.

Comment: @siride As noted in your question, I am not sure you have installed **`gnome-shell-extensions`**. Have you?

Comment: Yes. I even double checked just to make sure. Output of apt: `$ apt list gnome-shell-extensions
Listing... Done
gnome-shell-extensions/focal,focal,now 3.36.1-1 all [installed]`

Comment: @siride It looks installed indeed. Probably use `gnome-tweaks` to enable extensions and make sure you log out then log in back. Apart from that, I do not have other suggestions. I have it configured this way and running on my system without any issue.

Comment: @siride I noticed you wrote "and select the Gnome version and extension version, it only offers to download a Zip file" ... This is not how you install the extension! You just need to flip the **OFF** button on the top right to **ON** and the extension will be installed. Just like that.

Comment: That did it! It's totally not what I'd expect to upgrade, but there you have it.