# Cannot use gnome shell extensions

Tags: gnome-shell-extension

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04, and it seems to have a problem with gnome shell extensions:

[image: see scheenshot]

What can i do ? (There is log somewhere to read ?)

Edit: When install extension, i can see in journalctl:

```
févr. 08 10:58:46 V21BSJ gnome-shell[1686]: JS ERROR: Extension systemMonitor@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com: Error: Requiring GT
op, version none: Typelib file for namespace 'GTop' (any version) not found
                                             @/home/bastiensevajol/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/systemMonitor@gnome-shell-extensions.
gcampax.github.com/extension.js:4:14
                                             _callExtensionInit@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:425:13
                                             loadExtension@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:346:27
                                             callback@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionDownloader.js:234:39
                                             gotExtensionZipFile/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionDownloader.js:115:13
```

Edit2, after installed `sudo apt install gir1.2-gtop-2.0 libgtop2-dev`, extension fail to install with:

```
févr. 08 11:06:49 V21BSJ gnome-shell[1686]: JS ERROR: Extension systemMonitor@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com: TypeError: Main.messageTray._messageTrayMenuButton is undefined
                                             enable@/home/bastiensevajol/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/systemMonitor@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/extension.js:324:19
                                             wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/script/_legacy.js:82:27
                                             _callExtensionEnable@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:167:32
                                             loadExtension@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:349:26
                                             callback@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionDownloader.js:234:39
                                             gotExtensionZipFile/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionDownloader.js:115:13
```

Comment: [Firefox will not even try to install Gnome extensions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1275333/firefox-will-not-even-try-to-install-gnome-extensions) is also related.

Comment: Hello. First and second comment links don't solve. Following third comment link but same result. I added an error visible in journalctl in my question.

Comment: Try to reload Gnome ( Alt+F2 -> Type `r` -> Press Enter), then reload the page

Answer (score 0):

`systemMonitor@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com` is a very outdated extension. This is the reason of javascript errors.